# Can i publish MVC project so another pc can run it without any software?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish

The thing is, i made a **.net MVC project** for the college, now our professor want us to send it to him whether using CD or Email, how im supposed to do that ?

i mean i cant tell my instructor to download IIS or Visual Studio or whatever :|

any idea ?

Comment: I'm lost... If he wants a copy of it, and he is the professor, surely he knows what he needs in order to run it? It sounds like he wants you to zip up the entire folder (your solution, projects etc) and send the lot

Comment: I assume he means "the source". If I also assume this course is related to computing, one hopes a professor would know that a web-server doesn't *normally* run just from a CD without additional software, unless that was explicitly part of the stated design specification (i.e. some kind of executable that spins up a local http server on TCP)

Comment: Ya Dave he wants the entire project, and @MarcGravell no actually he wants everything not just the source,im pretty sure he doesnt even know what MVC is, anyhow if there's no way to do that, then what's exactly required to run a project after publishing it into a folder using visual studio ?

Comment: @user2962142 you don't need visual studio to host an MVC app; IIS Express would be enough

Answer (score 0):

I think you should host it somewhere (there are places where you can do it for free), and send him the source code with the URL to access the actual working homework.

Comment: Well, he asked for a soft copy on CD, but i guess i'll ignore that and do what u just said, thanks alot.